# Getting error on java program stackoverflow with program not collecting data and ending

Tags: java, algorithm, csv, quicksort, insertion-sort

I'm new to programming and was working on a program that stores the execution times in two arrays, timeInsertionSort and timeQuickSort, and then written to a CSV file named "execution_times.csv". I run my program and it never stops. The program is supposed to go to L = 200,000 and stop. Need help and dont know how to fix. What in the code needs to be fixed if u can please provide code

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SortingAlgorithms {
   
   public static void insertionSort(int[] arr) {
      int n = arr.length;
      for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
         int key = arr[j];
         int i = j - 1;
         while (i >= 0 && arr[i] > key) {
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
            i--;
         }
         arr[i + 1] = key;
      }
   }
   
   public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
      if (left < right) {
         int pivotIndex = partition(arr, left, right);
         quickSort(arr, left, pivotIndex - 1);
         quickSort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, right);
      }
   }
   
   private static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
      int pivot = arr[right];
      int i = left - 1;
      for (int j = left; j < right; j++) {
         if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(arr, i, j);
         }
      }
      swap(arr, i + 1, right);
      return i + 1;
   }
   
   private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
      int temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = temp;
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Random rand = new Random();
      int L = 200000;
      int[] arr = new int[L];
      long[] timeInsertionSort = new long[L];
      long[] timeQuickSort = new long[L];
      for (int n = 1; n <= L; n++) {
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = rand.nextInt(n);
         }
         long start = System.nanoTime();
         insertionSort(arr);
         long end = System.nanoTime();
         timeInsertionSort[n-1] = end - start;
         start = System.nanoTime();
         quickSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
         end = System.nanoTime();
         timeQuickSort[n-1] = end - start;
      }
      // Write the execution times to a CSV file
      try {
         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("execution_times.csv", "UTF-8");
         writer.println("n,TInsertionSort(n),TQuickSort(n)");
         for (int n = 1; n <= L; n++) {
            writer.println(n + "," + timeInsertionSort[n-1] + "," + timeQuickSort[n-1]);
         }
         writer.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Data goes to csv file

Comment: Either it never stops or it stops with an exception. It can't be both. Secondly, the stack trace will give information where exactly the error occurred. Typically the stack will run out when you have recursion. The only place in your code where you use recursion is in quickSort. Your QuickSort algorithm can potentially use a lot of stack space when there are a lot of duplicate values. Looking at how you produce random values, your arrays will usually have a lot of duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

Your test is very unfair:

```
     insertionSort(arr);
     ...
     quickSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
```

gives `quickSort` an already sorted array, and forces it into its worst case. 200000 stack frames is quite enough to overflow the stack. To be fair, make a copy of the array, and sort the copies independently.